# Oracle insert from multiple selects

Tags: oracle, insert

I'm trying to find a way to insert into an amalgamated table the results from multiple selects. A pseudo example below...

```
SELECT T1.VAL1,T1.VAL2,T1.VAL3 FROM TABLE1 T1
SELECT T2.VAL4,T2.VAL5,T2.VAL6 FROM TABLE2 T2

FOR ALL T1 LOOP
    FOR ALL T2 LOOP
        INSERT INTO TABLE3 T3
        (COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6)
        VALUES
        (T1.VAL1,T1.VAL2,T1.VAL3,T2.VAL4,T2.VAL5,T2.VAL6)
    END
END
```

So if T1 returns 25 rows and T2 returns 100, I will get a total of 2,500 rows inserted into T3.

Thanks in advance.

K

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CROSS JOIN`. There is no need of `LOOP`.

```
INSERT INTO table3 t3 (
    col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    col4,
    col5,
    col6
)
    SELECT
        t1.val1,
        t1.val2,
        t1.val3,
        t2.val4,
        t2.val5,
        t2.val6
    FROM
        table1 t1
        CROSS JOIN table2 t2;
```